# Rails Image loads when visiting URL directly but does not when redirected to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When visiting the page directly of which its view looks as following:

```
<img src='assets/logo.jpg',height="400", width="1600"></img>

<%= render 'form' %>

<div style="text-align:center;">

<%= link_to 'Register', new_user_path %>

</div>
```

The pointed asset loads, but when this view is redirected to the asset does not load.

What is rails doing that I dont know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use `image_tag` helper:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

your example instead:

```
<img src='assets/logo.jpg',height="400", width="1600"></img>
```

you must use:

```
<%= image_tag("logo.jpg"), :size => "1600x400" %>
```

Regards!